# sed - join two commands, number lines

Tags: sed, numbers, line

I'm trying to number the lines, but I need to use the -i parameter of sed, how can I join these 2 commands?

```
sed '=' file.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ => /'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to re-write the file than using -i

With `sponge` from the moreutils package

```sh
sed '=' file.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ => /' | sponge file.txt
```

With a temp file

```sh
tmp=$(mktemp)
sed '=' file.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ => /' > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file.txt
```

Or, if you don't have to use sed, GNU awk

```sh
gawk -i inplace '{print NR, "=>", $0}' file.txt
```

or perl

```sh
perl -i -pe 's/^/$. => /' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -zi 's/\n$//;s#.*#echo "&"|sed =|sed "N;s/\\n/ => /"#e' file
```

Run a sed pipe line within a sed invocation.